# PermanentTaskFailure on deferred : permanent failure attempting to execute task

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm reading a lot of this kind error in my application's log lately:

```
Permanent failure attempting to execute task
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 258, in post
    run(self.request.body)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 124, in run
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 146, in run_from_datastore
    raise PermanentTaskFailure()
PermanentTaskFailure
```

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502215/permanenttaskfailure-in-appengine-deferred-library) other related question with similar issues, it seems that the problem could be *Python path manipulation*.
The problem here is that in the stacktrace there's no indication of what is causing the trouble.

I'm not doing any path shenanigans on my source code and I really can't find what could be generate this kind of issue.

Sources:
[worker.py](https://github.com/systempuntoout/stackprinter/blob/master/app/utility/worker.py) - contains the deferred functions
[admin.py](https://github.com/systempuntoout/stackprinter/blob/master/app/controllers/admin.py) - admin controllers that calls deferred tasks
[stackprinterdownloader.py](https://github.com/systempuntoout/stackprinter/blob/master/app/core/stackprinterdownloader.py)- core lib that calls other deferred tasks

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

The particular case in which this exception is being raised indicates that you deferred a task with a payload that was too big to fit on the task queue, so deferred stored the extra data to the datastore. When it attempted to execute the task, however, the entity it stored the extra data in no longer existed, leading to the permanent failure. Perhaps you deleted the entity yourself before the task had a chance to execute?

Comment: thanks for your help, I don't have delete() method calls in the source code. Could the problem raise also in case of updates?

Comment: @systempuntoout No - this is occurring because the datastore entity that stores the data for the deferred task, of type `_DeferredTaskEntity` was deleted from the datastore before the task could execute. Either you deleted it using the admin console, or your code did. It's also possible, though unlikely, that the task already executed successfully, but threw an exception after deleting the data but before finishing. How often do you see this error?

Comment: I don't mess with _DeferredTaskEntity, really . It happened at 06:25PM of the 01-07 with a burst of 31 errors in a row; then happened again at 03:43PM of the 01-12 with 40 errors circa. I will fill an issue in case it will raise again

Comment: happened again at 04:40AM of 01-20. Two errors of the same type.